# iPad scales iPhone app incorrectly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

When I run the app on the iPad it uses currently the 4 inch screen which does not fit on the screen of an iPad, the app is an iPhone only app, but I want to run it on the iPad with scaling up the 3.5 inch screen.

How can I force the iPad to use the 3.5 inch screen and not the 4 inch?

And also the status bar is shown on the iPad and not on the iPhone, why is that also different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status bar on iPad in combatibility mode is completely outside of your reach. It's displayed on the edge of your screen not on the edge of the application window. This behavior cannot be modified by the application. Logically, you need the normal iPad status bar and you can't have another in the application. On the other hand, there is no reason to hide the iPad status bar because it can never overlap the application in compatibility mode.

The 4-inch is strange because iPads always show iPhone applications as 3.5 inch. If you see bad dimensions on the screen, then it's a bug in your code. Make sure you are setting frame sizes correctly.

Comment: you were right with the 4-inch issue, I was setting the auto layout constraints not correctly. However, I don't get the issue with the status bar, in the iPhone app I'm hiding always the status bar, but on iPad it is still there.

Comment: @user1463853 Added a better explanation.